# lambda expression to query a collection by a collection

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to create a lambda expression to query a collection by a collection

In a EF code first environment, I have the following data objects

I have a class named price

```
public class Price
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
    public virtual  Item Item  { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PriceOption> PriceOptions { get; set; }
}
```

And a related class named

```
public class PriceOption
{
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public int PriceId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PriceId")]
    public virtual Price Price { get; set; }

    public int OptionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OptionId")]
    public virtual Option Option { get; set; }

}
```

I have two search criteria

```
int ItemId

List<int> optionIds
```

I want to create a lambda expression to select all prices that are equil to the ItemId (easy) and where the PriceOptions 
collection contains all of the optionIds.

The Idea is something like this but of course this it just to show what I am trying to achive.

```
List<Price> prices = _priceRepository.FindAll().Where(x => x.ItemId == item.Id && x.PriceOptions.All(y => y.OptionId == optionIds)).ToList();
```

Thank you for your help

Earl

Comment: Sorry, the web page messed up my formatting for the search criteria but now I fixed it. I need to use optionIds to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following LINQ query based on `Contains` and `Count` methods produces a simpler (thus eventually faster) SQL query:

```
var matchCount = optionIds.Count;
var prices = _priceRepository.FindAll()
              .Where(p => p.ItemId == ItemId &&
                  p.PriceOptions.Count(po => optionIds.Contains(po.OptionId)) == matchCount)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you! I needed to refine my code but at the end it worked as expected ;-)